# remembering window scroll position after refreshing a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

just a problem thats been annoying me.
I make changes to the database through an ajax call, refresh the div and all that goes okay, but still scroll to the top of the page.

This is what ive tried:

```
function postdislike(pid, user, uid) {
"use strict";
//user clicks dislike

var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "sections/sendpostdislike.php";
var vars = "pid=" + pid + "&user=" + user + "&uid=" + uid;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200)
    {
        var response = hr.responseText;

        //scrollsave = $('#posted_by-'+pid);
        //scrollsave = $(document).scrollTop();






        $('#profilePosts').load('../'+ target +' #profilePosts > *');
        //$('#posted_by-'+pid).load('../'+ target +' #posted_by-'+pid + ' > *');
        //$('#posted_by-'+pid).scrollTop();

        $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: ($('#posted_by-'+pid).offset().top-300)},0);





        //$('#reactsub-' + pid).load('../'+ target +'#reactsub-' + pid + ' > *');

    }
};
hr.send(vars);





}
```

But no matter what I do, the page always jumps to the top. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: managed to get it to scroll with this, but being animate, it still jumps to the top before scrolling. Is there a way I can get it to just stay there without jumping to the top to begin with?

Answer (score 4):

You're using

```
$(window).scrollTop(scrollsave);
```

First, `scrollTop()` doesn't take any arguments.

Second, if you invoke `scrollTop()` on the window element, you're scrolling to the top of the window.

Invoke `scrollTop()` on your `#profilePosts`, then it should work.

Comment: I tried:
scrollsave = $('#posted_by-'+pid).scrollTop();
then after the refresh
$('#posted_by-'+pid).scrollTop(scrollsave);
and no dice.
Also just tried after the refresh
$('#posted_by-'+pid).scrollTop();
and still no dice.

Im trying to scroll down to an inner div of the outer div being refreshed

Answer (score 0):

This worked...

```
function postdislike(pid, user, uid) {
"use strict";

event.preventDefault();

//user clicks dislike

var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "sections/sendpostdislike.php";
var vars = "pid=" + pid + "&user=" + user + "&uid=" + uid;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200)
    {
        var response = hr.responseText;

        //scrollsave = $('#posted_by-'+pid);
        //scrollsave = $(document).scrollTop();






        $('#profilePosts').load('../'+ target +' #profilePosts > *');
        //$('#posted_by-'+pid).load('../'+ target +' #posted_by-'+pid + ' > *');
        //$('#posted_by-'+pid).scrollTop();

        //$('html, body').animate({
         //scrollTop: ($('#posted_by-'+pid).offset().top-300)},0);


        //$('#reactsub-' + pid).load('../'+ target +'#reactsub-' + pid + ' > *');

        $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });

    }
};
hr.send(vars);

return false;



}
```